# Is it possible to draw BORDER for Highcharts PlotBand LABEL?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to apply Border for Highcharts PLOTBAND Label. I Think, it doesn't have a border attribute to support. BorderWidth and BorderColor attribute doesn't work here.. Please suggest a way to apply a border for plotband label,

My Code ..

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            plotBands: [{
                color: '#c5c5c5',
                from: 0,
                to: 115,
                label: {
                    text: 'Plot band',
                    **BorderWidth** : 2,
                    **BorderColor** : 'red'
                   }
```

Code Continues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not in that way.

You can use the `useHTML` property,  combined with the `style` settings to affect most style attributes of the label.

```
label: {
    useHTML: true,
        text: '<span class="label">Target Area</span>',
        style: {
            backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
            border:'1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.75)',
            borderRadius:'3px',
            color:'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            fontWeight:'bold',
            padding:'3px'
        }
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/59/